# helmet.js custom options for one middleware while enabling others

Tags: javascript, helmet.js

I want to set some custom options for one of the `helmet.js` middlewares but I don't understand if by doing so the other middlewares are enabled or I have to enable them explicitly ?

From `helmet.js` docs:

```
// Sets all of the defaults, but overrides `script-src` and disables the default `style-src`
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
      "script-src": ["'self'", "example.com"],
      "style-src": null,
    },
  })
);
```

Should I add `app.use(helmet())` before the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.use(helmet())` includes all of Helmet's default middlewares with their default options.

`app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy())` only includes the Content Security Policy middleware. In other words, you won't get the rest of Helmet's middlewares.

To include all of Helmet's defaults and customize the CSP middleware, specify it under the top-level `helmet()`:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      // ...
    },
  })
);
```